# lsblk: command not found Why?

Tags: buildroot

In my Buildroot distro I want call **lsblk** but

```
lsblk: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

if you [haven't got](https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15226) lsblk just set BR2_PACKAGE_UTIL_LINUX_BINARIES=y in buildroot.
[image]